# WAS7 Fixpack21Issue

Tags: websphere-7

I have WAS7 installed & applied fixpack21 last week, since then i was seeing jax-ws web services xml response contains xsi:nil="true" even the element had a value. this is happening for decimal fields. Any thoughts please?
Thanks

Comment: Didn't encountered that on 7.0.0.21 but did you try 7.0.0.23 ? maybe it was fixed there if anybody else encountered it

Comment: no, didn't try fixpack23, first i want to find the issue what it is & why its causing?
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You could check and see if you find some APAR that could affect this http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27014463